# Run Vagrant on Amazon Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, amazon-workspaces

I'm trying to set up a web development environment on Amazon Workspaces running Amazon Linux AMI, but I didn't find a way to install Vagrant on the machine. I would like to have a virtual webdev machine for various practical reasons, but it seems that I can't run vagrant as AWS is already virtualised.
Is that correct, or is there a way to install and run vagrant/virtualbox containers on AWS Workspace?

Comment: This question might have more traction on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Thanks @txyoji, that might explain the thumbs down this question received initially .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS workspaces only offers a limited number of packages within its repo manager, so you won't find vagrant there. But you can manually install the repo using the CentOS download on their [website](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html). For example, this worked for me inside my Linux AMI WorkSpace:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.1.2/vagrant_2.1.2_x86_64.rpm
yum install vagrant_2.1.2_x86_64.rpm
```

Now a WorkSpace is essentially a virtualized environment, so its unlikely you will be able to run a vm inside it - See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/46960/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-virtual-machine-inside-another-virtual-machine).

However vagrant offers a number of providers other than the default - including [aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws), which will allow you to spin up a vagrant box on an ec2 instance rather than locally. You can install it as follows:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

And follow the configuration steps [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws)